# Issue in deploying Angular NodeJs app on Google Cloud Build

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, npm, google-cloud-platform

Im having trouble deploying my app through GCP Cloud Build.
Do I have to update to GLIBC_2.28 but if so how do I do that on GCP Clould Build?

I'm also assuming it could be the Nodejs version but I specified node 16.15.0 in my cloudbuild.yaml and package.json files... I thought that the problem was only for versions 18x.

In my app.yaml I also use a runtime of Nodejs16.
deploying my application works in the GCP Cloud Shell but I'm having troubles with GCP Cloud Build.

```
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 32fb7223-bf43-47ae-bd3b-787ba77c43f0 status: FAILURE
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/@scarf/scarf
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./report.js
npm ERR! node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-05T12_26_54_920Z-debug-0.log
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=europe-west1/32fb7223-bf43-47ae-bd3b-787ba77c43f0?project=772319101637
```

Edit:
Heres my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
# Install node packages
- name: node:16.15.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
# Build productive files
- name: node:16.15.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']
# Deploy to google cloud app egnine
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud app deploy']
```

Comment: Can you add your cloud build YAML file to the question, it will make it easier to assist

Comment: ive just edited my post with my cloudbuild YAML file @rossco

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my app.yaml file. I switched back to a python27 runtime (which was giving me an issue with files not being found by the handler after building with no problem) but I added a third handler and it works.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(js|css|svg|png)(|\.map))$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*)(|\.map)

  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/.

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

skip_files:
  - e2e/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.json$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
  - ^LICENSE
```